# Holding top trophy

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Gershwin recalled a song (4)
5. Musical intervals the net has essentially ignored (6)
12. Scavenger of old is trapped in darkness – poor lad (7)
13. Rearranged 1 across missing a distinctive quality (3)
14. One unfinished toy becomes graven image (4)
16. Set out time for a type of match sometimes played in 11 down (4)
17. 11 down losing territory, leading to anger (3)
18. Storage space covered half-heartedly, in retrospect (5)
20. Summit talk's introduction omitted (4)
22. Bad start for lead character: killed in Dallas for making tea? (7)
24. Right or left part of a bird's wing (5)
25. 11 down's leader's way I half-heartedly look for (9)
27. Dirty word after 11 down city (9)
28. Excellent profit, repeatedly (5)
31. Southern 20 across in Canada's providing catchphrases (7)
33. 11 down city's material used by wine industry (4)
36. Creepy motel owner and vampires maybe ingesting drug (5)
38. Black piece of humour getting no laughs in the end (3)
40. Agent retired during anti-Semitic ranting (4)
41. A vegetable counter for Native American (4)
43. Luxurious vehicle's missing a piece at the front, if you ask me (3, abbr.)
44. Sensor Anna holds rank below Jack (7)
45. Holy book's first part omitted, among other things, an inspiring mythological character (6)
46. Kind of party for small children's game (4)

**Down**
1. Mate in French Defence's opening, in the centre? (4)
2. Conlang words spoken at the altar (3)
3. Let's each of us ring Andrew, finally (5)
4. Enthusiastic supporter of someone doing skilled work behind piano (8)
6. Lengthen weekend with repeated shelling (3)
7. Sensory organ recognizes aurally (4)
8. Small child atop a large wreck (5)
9. Japanese form of intoxicated murmur sounds (5)
10. No time to be involved in commotion for gentleman (3)
11. Composer John and I descend 28 across (7)
15. In Cologne, the 17 across almost lead to insanity (7)
16. Opinions of three vacant players from Brooklyn (6)
19. Labourer working after gym class (4)
21. Purple dinosaur has large castle in 11 down (7)
23/32. Magic eagles playing sports in 11 down (6,5)
24. Retired swimmer seen with flyers and gymnasts (8)
25. City in China's north – it turned back animated ninja (7)
26. Ditch 39 down's relative with tall head (4)
29. Current Oscar winner, finally holding top trophy: 11 down Baldwin, maybe? (5)
30. Historical consonants left unused around northern part of Ancient Greece (5)
32. *(See 23 down)*
34. Shower in Ukraine (4)
35. Ends of thick hair (a Semi-Perm, for instance) (4)
37. 46 across's head on a silver dish (4)
39. Giant bird skinned Madagascar primate (3)
42. Maybe a worker is not wanting me? (3)

Comment: Missing clue added! Sorry about that.

Comment: No big deal! I've made much worse mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Overall, another nice puzzle! I especially liked

> 5-Across, 6-Down, and 30-Down -- all three of those had interesting forms of wordplay that occur pretty rarely, but they were still perfectly fair. (Hard for me to notate, though...)

Comment: l stiII can't see the picture. Maybe l have to post another answer.